# Handling Exception custom in JAX-WS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, jax-ws

I have web service, developed using JAX-WS. Now i wanted to throw SOAPFault with customized error codes on certain conditions.

I have a webfault:

```
@WebFault(name = "BankExceptionFault1_Fault", targetNamespace = NS.namespace)
```

public class BankException extends Exception {

```
private WebMethodStatus faultInfo;


public BankException(Errors error) {
    this(error, error.name());
}

public WebMethodStatus getFaultInfo() {
    return faultInfo;
}

public BankException(Errors error, String description) {
    super(error.getErrorCode());
    this.faultInfo = new WebMethodStatus(error, description);
}
```

}

And In some method, for a given condition, throws exception:

```
@Override
@WebMethod(operationName = "UpdateAccountRecord")
@WebResult(name = "Result")
@LogExecution
public WebMethodStatus updateAccountRecord(
        @WebParam(name = "Request") UpdateAccountRequest request) throws BankException {
    if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(specialMode)) {
        throw new BankException(Errors.INVALID_RUNNING_MODE,
                "Can't update account record. For updating need special running mode");
    }
    service.updateAccountRecord(request);
    return new WebMethodSuccessStatus();
}
```

In spring-mvc app, I want to catch my exception:

```
try {
        wsPort.updateAccountRecord(updateAccountRequest);
    } catch (BankException e) {
        throwException(e);
    }
    catch(RemoteAccessException e){
        throwException(e);
    }
```

But always return RemoteAccessException, if try to update account using sring-mvc app.
detailMessage:Could not access remote service at [http://localhost:8080/my-app-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/app/MyApp]
cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT

But if I use soapui for update account, returns correct exception:

> BNK00017
>                     Can't update account record. For updating need special running mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wsPort` is something like an injected `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`, then it's likely that your exception is being wrapped by `RemoteAccessException`. Try using `RemoteAccessException.getCause()` and see what you get...

Comment: This is a result: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT